# How to extract a value from a Python dictionary using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, unicode, key

I have a Python dictionary that looks like this...

```
{u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'Encountered " <ID> "asd "" at line 1, column 1.\nWas expecting:\n    <EOF> \n    ', u'location': u'query'}
```

How do I access the `u'message'` value using Javascript? It is being passed to the front end via Django REST Framework, shouldn't that convert it to a JSON object automatically? It isn't...

Comment: Javascript has no such syntax.  All strings are always Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py

```
import json

json_object = json.dumps(your_object)
```

In .html / .js

```
var json_object = {{json_object|safe}};
```

The .py side converts it to a valid JSON object. The tag in html escapes invalid json characters like "&"

In case you are sending your object as a string to your template then you have to convert it to JSON again via JSON, for instance:

```
JSON.parse("{{json_object}}");
```

Or if the object is a string or a Python dict on the Django views level:

```
json.loads(your_string)
```

To convert it into a json object

Comment: I just expanded my answer with more info. If you can't make it work you have a different problem because I just tested this process using json.dumps({u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'Encountered " <ID> "asd "" at line 1, column 1.\nWas expecting:\n    <EOF> \n    ', u'location': u'query'}); and it works

Comment: So that doesn't actually work, because apparently the "object" is actually a string. Is there a way to turn a string that is object into just an object?

Comment: json.loads(your_string) to convert a string into a json object in your view

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: How would I convert it do a json object? It is a dictionary object being sent to javascript from Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Django Rest should serve it as a valid JSON object in the first place. Otherwise you can stringify it, remap and eval as object for example - but it's not a good solution.